# Android: I deleted a package then I got ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, classnotfoundexception

I deleted a UI package which contained my fragment classes.
[The UI package I deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KCDo.png)

I then created new classes of the same name in the bustracker package
[What my project set up looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLdZc.png)

When I run the app I get the following error.

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.bustracker.ui.nearbyStops.nearbyStopsFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bustracker-cuWeKLTM_oUFXduWOdcaDA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.bustracker-cuWeKLTM_oUFXduWOdcaDA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 55 more
```

My question is, how do I get it to no longer look for **com.example.bustracker.ui.nearbyStops.nearbyStopsFragment**, but instead look for **com.example.bustracker.nearbyStopsFragment**?

Project has 4 classes, all of which you can find below.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_nearby_stops, R.id.nav_saved, R.id.nav_search)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_nearby_stops:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_view, new nearbyStopsFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_saved:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_view, new savedFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_view, new searchFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                }
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

nearbyStopsFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class nearbyStopsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby_stops, container, false);
    }
}
```

savedFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class savedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved, container, false);
    }
}
```

searchFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class searchFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It says this in your message: "Didn't find class "com.example.bustracker.ui.nearbyStops.nearbyStopsFragment"". So you are probably trying to call a fragment named nearbyStopsFragment which you earlier deleted. Since your question is really really bad I can't say for sure. Please read the rules and then post questions accordingly.

Comment: Agree with @SlothCoding that it is not clear what is going on, although a conclusion can be drawn that you are trying to load a fragment from the package you deleted.
It is best you read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add more detail to help others to help you.

Comment: Please show the full error (expand those 55 lines)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without seeing the code, but it looks like something in BaseDexClassLoader is trying to call something in the fragment file on line 125.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `activity/fragment` you will have, on top of the class, a lot of imports of packages you are using. There should be an import that says something like this:

```
import com.example.bustracker.ui.nearbyStops.nearbyStopsFragment;
```

Just change that into this new one:

```
import com.example.bustracker.nearbyStopsFragment;
```

If this doesn't work please provide your `JAVA` code with imports.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I converted some Java classes to Kotlin, So I find out that I need to add `id "kotlin-android"` plugin and `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"` in Module gradle and `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"` in project gradle